# how to interact with website using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, forms, httpurlconnection, interaction

Here is the story: There is a website with some form fields. After filling in the fields the user can click on search. By clicking the search button a list of **links** will be returned and shown underneath the form. If the number of links is **more than 10** the user can click on next which is a **javascript button**.

A part of a java program of mine connects to this website using **HttpUrlConnection** and sends the form data through the established connection. **Retrieving the first 10 links is not a problem**; I mean the connection with website, sending the field data, and getting the first 10 links is not a problem at all. My problem is how to get the next 10 links.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what exactly your javascript button does? If it performs an Ajax request to retrieve the next portion of links, you can make the same request using HttpUrlConnection, parse the output, and get your next 10 links.

Comment: the javascript button calls this:
function gotopage(n)
{
    document.searchform.action = '9292ov321.asp?pagenumber=' + n;
    document.searchform.submit();
}

Comment: If you want to go with HttpUrlConnection-based solution, you can do following: make a request to "http://yoursite/9292ov321.asp?pagenumber=2" and examine the output. Most likely it will be easy to parse XML or JSON stream. After you figure out how to parse the output and get the links from it, you can create a simple program that will make requests to "http://yoursite/9292ov321.asp?pagenumber=<N>" starting with page 0 (or 1), analyze the output, stop if there's less then 10 links, or continue with next page number, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). This frameworks behaves like a browser and allows you to navigate programmatically between pages at your will. It executes Javascript embedded in pages, too.

Comment: Thanks alot. If my efforts with HttpURLConnection wont have a good result I will consider learning and using HtmlUnit. At this moment I feel that I have done alot to know how HttpURLConnection works, so I dont want to give it up quickly :)

Comment: HttpUrlCollection is a good tool for simple use cases. Your needs are a little too complex, you have to execute Javascript to render a button. If you don't want to implement a Javascript interpreter and a DOM, I suggest you to use HtmlUnit and spare your precious time.

Comment: Apparently not so complex :-) Just hit '9292ov321.asp?pagenumber=' + n; in the loop and read the results until there's any.